# get the element from a Map with a given value in the Value

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map defined as `std::map<std::string, textInfo> tempMap;`
the textInfo class has some attributes as `textsize`,`textcolor`,`textfont` etc..
I want to select an item from this map that matches with a given value to an attribute in `textInfo` class.

for example if the Map contains

```
<"A",textInfo("10","Red","Verdana")>
<"B",textInfo("12","Green","Timesnewroman")>
<"C",textInfo("11","Blue","Cambria")>
```

I want to select the item that contains "Cambria" in it textfont attribute.
`<"C",textInfo("11","Blue","Cambria")>`

Comment: There is no bimap so you have to iterate the map and find it.

Comment: You can use more than ohne map. So for every attribute  an own map with pointers to the original dataset.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) should work for your needs.

Sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

struct textInfo
{
   std::string textsize;
   std::string textcolor;
   std::string textfont;
};

int main()
{
   std::map<std::string, textInfo> m = 
   {
      {"A", {"10","Red","Verdana"}},
      {"B", {"12","Green","Timesnewroman"}},
      {"C", {"11","Blue","Cambria"}}
   };

   auto iter = std::find_if(m.begin(),
                            m.end(),
                            [](std::pair<std::string, textInfo> const& item)
                            { return (item.second.textfont == "Cambria");});
   if ( iter != m.end() )
   {
      auto& item = iter->second;
      std::cout << item.textsize << ", " << item.textcolor << ", " << item.textfont << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
11, Blue, Cambria
```

Comment: you'd better comment that the above code only works in c++11 :)

Comment: @walker it works in the *current* version of C++, which at the moment is C++14, so I'd say that's fine. :-)

Comment: @walker, hopefully the OP can utilize the core idea if they are not able to use a C++11 compiler.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Speaking of c++14, can we modify '[](std::pair<std::string, textInfo> const& item)' to '[](auto&& item)' in c++14? I think it will seems more concisely.

Comment: @walker yes, you can use `auto` for the lambda argument - `[](const auto& item)` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access maps directly via a key, here your std::string. To search for a value or even a variable inside a value like it's the case here you have to iterate over the whole map.

```
std::map<std::string, textInfo>::const_iterator it = tempMap.begin();
for (; it != tempMap.end(); ++it)
{
   if (0 == tempMap[(*it)].textfont.equals("Cambria")) // You could use == operator if it's a std::string
   {
      break; // found
   }
}
// Do something with the found item. If the iterator is tempMap.end(), nothing found!
```

Look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) for more informations.

Comment: Hi @Programmerzzz if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.